# Serve static JS-App from directory in Laravel for authorized users

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-jetstream

I have a Js app. It has its own directory and everything it needs is in that directory. I want to use this app in Laravel project now. But it should only be available for logged in users. Now I do not know how to do it. I would use cookie-authentication, but how should it work? If JS app is in public directory it is always open for access and has no access to csrf token. If it is in resourses I can only provide single files in view. How can I make a whole directory available? At the moment I see only one possibility:

web.php

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/jsapp', function () {
    return view("jsapp");
})->name('jsapp');

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/jsapp/{path?}', function (Request $req, $path) {
    return serve_file_somehow("path_to_project_root", $path);
});
```

This Js-App polls the server regularly to check if the user is still logged in.My question how to implement this `serve_file_somehow` feature? Or maybe there are other solutions for this situation? Is there any kind of .htaccess -magic that can be implemented?

Js-App directory structure:

```
resources/views/jsapp
-- index.html
    <html>
        <link href="css/styles.css" />
        <script src="js/index.js />
    </html>
-- css/styles.css
-- js/index.js
-- images/img1.jpg
```

What bothers me is that you reimplement the functions of a web server via PHP/Laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should serve the index.html file contents through a blade template
`index.blade.php`

```html
<html>
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <link href="/css/styles.css" />
  <script src="/js/index.js />
</html>
```

with a protected route:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/jsapp', function () {
    return view("jsapp.index");
})->name('jsapp');
```

and put all javascript and css files in the `public` directory.

Comment: cool I like this idea. A small disadvantage is that js-App files are not completely in their directory.Und natürlich dann immer zugreifbar sind unabhängig davon ob der User eingeloggt ist. Aber fehlende csrf_token und cookie verbietet Zugriff auf die interne Daten.

Comment: Ups, in english please :) And of course they are always accessible regardless if the user is logged in or not. But missing csrf_token and cookie forbids access to the internal data.

Comment: Intentionally suggested the scripts to be public, because that is the usual way. That way, it enables better caching control, among others. If it is about security, that should sit on the API / internal data.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to get CSRF token via `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie, which `Laravel` sets automatically. If you don't have access to the resources directory, or want to have all your JS app in one directory. Then you can also use this method.

```
 <script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-XSRF-TOKEN': $.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN')
        }
    });
 </script>
```